# Pegar status code da atual requisição

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, http-status

Eu tenho um requisição feita por *JqueryFileDownload* que quando ocorre erro
o servidor me retorna diferentes tipos de status. Eu preciso agir no cliente de acordo com esses erros. Diferente do *jquery* *ajax* eu não consigo pelo *fileDownload* receber o status atual da requisição. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma via *javascript* pegar esse status. Lembrando que a chamada continuara sendo feita pelo *fileDownload*.

```
$.fileDownload(url)
    .done(function () {                     
        jSuccess("com sucesso!", "Sucesso");
    })
    .fail(function () {
        var erro = //quero pegar o status aqui

 });
```

Comment: Verifique os parâmetros passado em `fail`. Faça `console.log(arguments)` pra ver se tem o argumento com o código lá.

Comment: o fail possui dois parametros: xhr, url... O xhr retorna um html e url a mesma url de requisicao.

Comment: Tente `xhr.status`. Veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344145/how-to-get-response-status-code-from-jquery-ajax

Comment: desculpe não é um xhr e sim um responseHtml